# While reading large amount of data in bytes the while loop is getting tripped for the last few bytes

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I'm sending byte of 8254789 bytes. It is undergoing the loop but when it reaches the at 8246597 and has to read 8192 bytes. It is going out from while loop to nowhere. Can someone explain please, what is the problem?

```
 public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream stream, int initialLength)
{
    // If we've been passed an unhelpful initial length, justS
    // use 32K.
    if (initialLength < 1)
    {
        initialLength = 32768;
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[3824726];
    int read = 0;
    int chunk;
    try
    {

        while ((chunk = stream.Read(buffer, read, 3824726 - read)) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Length of chunk" + chunk);
            read += chunk;
            Console.WriteLine("Length of read" + read);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                stream.Close();
                return buffer;
            }
            // If we've reached the end of our buffer, check to see if there's
            // any more information
            if (read == buffer.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Length of Buffer" + buffer.Length);
                int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();

                // End of stream? If so, we're done
                if (nextByte == -1)
                {
                    return buffer;
                }

                // Nope. Resize the buffer, put in the byte we've just
                // read, and continue
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
                Console.WriteLine("Length of newBuffer" + newBuffer.Length);
                Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, buffer.Length);
                newBuffer[read] = (byte)nextByte;
                buffer = newBuffer;
                read++;                        
            }
        }

        // Buffer is now too big. Shrink it.
        byte[] ret = new byte[read];
        Array.Copy(buffer, ret, read);
        return ret;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { throw ex; }
}
```

Comment: Why not to simply `Stream.Copy` to `MemeoryStream` ? Will be as slow as your code on large streams, but at least trivial to write/read.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't write your stream loops like that. Instead try something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int read = -1;
while((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    // ... use read bytes in buffer here
}
```

You're attempting to adjust your offset each time, but you don't need to because use cursors - so you're basically skipping ahead.

Comment: Can u explain me how to collect the whole data into a new buffer indide the loop which u have given.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response. Please do respond again for my above qurries. thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also the buffer size I dont know. Just for testing purpose I had put it as 3824726.

Comment: @user1805948 choose any arbitrary size for the buffer. I usually use 16 * 1024 (16KB).